# GDI C# Remove Background After Skewing Image

Tags: c#, gdi+, gdi

I'm trying to make a skewed image with a transparent background from a inputted square image.

So far the skewing part is working, but the background of the unskewed image remains. How can I remove the unskewed image from the background and replace it with a transparent background?

So far I've tried using `.Clear(Color.Transparent)` but it only seems to make the entire image clear or do nothing.

Code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Point[] destinationPoints = {
        new Point (150, 20),
        new Point (40, 50),
        new Point (150, 300)
        };

       Image before = Image.FromFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop),
        "before.png"));
       var gr = Graphics.FromImage(before);
       //drawing an ellipse
       Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Red);
       gr.DrawEllipse(myPen, new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 300));
       //applying skewed points
       gr.DrawImage(before, destinationPoints);
       var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop),
        "after.png");
       before.Save(path);
    }
}
```

before.png

[image: before]

after.png

[image: after.png]

rough desired result

[image: rough desired result]

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've tried using `Graphics.Clear(Color.Transparent)` but it only seems
>   to clear the entire image

Indeed; you need to **select** to part you want to clear first, which is **everything but** the part you draw skewed..:

```
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
..
GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
gp.AddRectangle(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, before.Size)); 
gp.AddPolygon(destinationPoints);
```

This first selects the whole image and then cuts a hole at the skewed destination area.

(Note: [GraphicsPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath?view=netframework-4.8) only lets you *add* to the figures it contains; the rule for the default windingmode is: areas get added unless they overlap what is already there. Parts that overlap once get subtracted etc..)

Now you have two options to clear the unskewed part of the image.

You can either **fill** with transparent:

```
gr.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;
gr.FillPath(Brushes.Transparent, gp);
```

Or you can  **clear** with transparent:

```
gr.SetClip(gp);
gr.Clear(Color.Transparent);
```

**This should work for your example image.**

Unfortunately this will not work once your image contains non-opaque pixels in the skewed portion. Here the original pixels  will still shine through.

So the solution for such a case is rather straightforward: **Do not draw over the original bitmap but create a new one** with the backcolor you wish and draw onto the new one:

```
Image after = new Bitmap(before.Width, before.Height);
var gr = Graphics.FromImage(after );
gr.Clear(Color.yourChoice);
// now draw as needed..
```